# How to use regex to limit domains?

Tags: html, regex, email, input

I'm making an html5 form and only want users to sign up with .edu or .gov email addresses. What would the regex look like for that? I know it must be checked serverside as well, but one step at a time.

Example:

```
<input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) I came up with this using a [simplified RFC 2822 compatible pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373724/8291949):

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,62}[A-Za-z0-9]\.)+(edu|gov)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MCV07c/1/)

The major difference is how the domain part is evaluated. I took this from my previous answer.

```html
<form action="javascript:console.log('ok')">
<input type="text" name="domain" 
pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,62}[A-Za-z0-9]\.)+(edu|gov)" title="Sorry, only email addresses from .edu and .org domains are allowed.">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(domain|domain2)\.(edu|gov)$
```

[Demo](https://www.regextester.com/94044)